# Using Invoke with a UI element that extends Application Context?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, invoke, notifyicon

I have a taskBarIcon element extending Application Context from which my entire UI is designed. This is because the original functionality of the application was to run a background process and simply provide the icon as a confirmation that the app was running.
However, I am now adding additional functionality in the form of a menu that may be accessed by right clicking the icon, and since the core functionality is running on one thread, and the icon on the main thread, I am having issues accessing the icon in the simple case of needing to display a notification bubble. There are no other points at which the two threads may be accessing the same memory, so synchronization is not really an issue.

I am used to Java, in which this process is far simpler. I've read the articles I can find regarding the Invoke-Delegate dance that C# requires, but none are specific to an object extending Application Context. My current implementation is far too unpredictable to be production safe.

My question is this: How do I send the message to the other process to display the notification bubble, without disturbing the accessibility of the menu? Specifically, a simple example with a UI class extending Application Context and a class on a separate thread calling the invoke method would be very helpful.

I really appreciate any help!

badPanda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just as well use a `SynchronizationContext` object that you assign to `SynchronizationContext.Current` on the same thread that you create the notification bubble.  You would then pass your `SynchronizationContext` object into whatever component the menu is on and it would use `context.Send(....)` to send a message.  Or, if you have access to the notification bubble component or the form it's on, you could do `form.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {....});`